# How to see field from second table in loopback?

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, loopbackjs

I have this 2 models in loopback one called Permissions and the second one called langs_translate.

The tables look like this:

Prmission:

```
--------------------------
| id | icon      | link  |
--------------------------
| 1  | dashboard | home  |
--------------------------
| 2  | users     | users |
--------------------------
| 3  | inbox     | inbox |
--------------------------

 ...
 "relations": {
   "langsTranslates": {
     "type": "hasMany",
     "model": "langs_translates",
     "foreignKey": "permission_id"
   }
 },
 ....
```

lang_tranlate

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| id | label     | permission_id  | lang | translate  |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | HOME_TXT  | 1              | eng  | Dashboard  |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | USERS_TXT | 2              | eng  | Users      |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | INBOX_TXT | 3              | eng  | Inbox      |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 4  | USERS_TXT | 2              | heb  | לקוחות     |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 5  | INBOX_TXT | 3              | heb  |  הודעות    |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 6  | HOME_TXT  | 1              | heb  | לוח בקרה   | 
-------------------------------------------------------

...
"relations": {
  "permissions": {
    "type": "belongsTo",
    "model": "permissions",
    "foreignKey": "permission_id"
  }
},
...
```

I want to see the "icon" from the permission table and connect to lang_translate table by the key "permission_id" and take from those table the field "label".
but it only take the fields from the permission table. i'm using this code to take the data:

```
$rootScope.menus = Permissions.find({
    include: 
        {"relation": "langsTranslates"},
    filter: {
        where: {
            lang : "heb"
        }
    } 
}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

a lot of thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify `include` under the `filter` key:

```
Permissions.find({
    filter: {
        where: { lang : "heb" },
        include: {"relation": "langsTranslates"},
    } 
}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Technically `where`, `include`, `order`, `fields`, `limit` and `offset` are all different types of filters, and with angular SKD it should be specified like that. Check the [AngularJS SDK docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/AngularJS-JavaScript-SDK.html#model-resource-api) for more info.